# How do I convert a desktop webscraper to a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping

I have a desktop webscraper application written using C#.NET. 
It works very simply. The user imports input data in txt/csv/Excel. The app exports scraped and orginized results in an output file (csv, html).

How can I make this accessible online, as a website?
I haven't done web programming before (only desktop) and I do not know any web programming languages. But I think I can learn ASP.NET and create similar webscraper functionality with it.

What kind of webhosting requirements do I have?

Comment: One would *rewrite* it as a "website" (whatever that means). Not a Real Question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is turn your desktop application into a library. Turn your EXE into a DLL with an API that does specific functions. This means separating functional operations from UI operations. Then, build a web application that uses this library to offer the same functionality online.
If you want to learn something new to build web applications, I suggest ASP.NET MVC and not ASP.NET Web Forms. MVC is much closer to web development than web forms.

As for web hosting requirements, Any web host that support ASP.NET should be able to run ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thank you Amr for this tips! Very helpful! What about webhosting requirements for asp.net mvc?

Comment: Any web host that support ASP.NET should be able to run ASP.NET MVC, it's just a library that runs on .NET

Answer (score -1):

I have done a little with ASP.NET but I think [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185302/Web-Scraping-in-ASP-NET-with-Regular-Expression-Ma) will help you